# ANR com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, android-billing

Ever since modifying my code to use the Android billing library instead of the old IABHelper from the sample app, I have been getting a lot of ANRs with this trace below. Anyone have any idea how to solve that? there isn't a single line of my code on the trace.

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x73b53ac0 self=0x77558a3a00
  | sysTid=17097 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x775a8109b0
  | state=S schedstat=( 21526708836 9207381756 40660 ) utm=1497 stm=655 core=5 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7ff197c000-0x7ff197e000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 000000000001da2c  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
  #01  pc 00000000000e1ee4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable16WaitHoldingLocksEPNS_6ThreadE+152)
  #02  pc 00000000004e35c8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3artL12GoToRunnableEPNS_6ThreadE+440)
  #03  pc 00000000004e33c8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art12JniMethodEndEjPNS_6ThreadE+28)
  #04  pc 000000000098a7bc  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_os_BinderProxy_transactNative__ILandroid_os_Parcel_2Landroid_os_Parcel_2I+220)
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative (Native method)
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact (Binder.java:751)
  at com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService$Stub$Proxy.isBillingSupported (IInAppBillingService.java:320)
  at com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientImpl$BillingServiceConnection.onServiceConnected (BillingClientImpl.java:839)
  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected (LoadedApk.java:1818)
  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run (LoadedApk.java:1847)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:808)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:101)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:166)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7425)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:245)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

Comment: Have you been able to determine the cause? I have the same problem, mainly with Android 8 devices.

Comment: There is a ticket on the google issues site, looks like they are reading a file in the ui thread. Supposedly fix coming by the end of the month. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123117066

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears to be an issue with the Play Store reading a file on the UI thread https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123117066