# ANR on onServiceConnected in BillingClientImpl

Tags: android, android-billing

I've started getting this anr at android google BillingClient on developer console. any idea what could be causing this or where should I look to find possible cause.[image]

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
      | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x7457c390 self=0xb4df6500
      | sysTid=4010 nice=-4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb6f9bc00
      | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=267 stm=94 core=3 HZ=100
      | stack=0xbe63f000-0xbe641000 stackSize=8MB
      | held mutexes=
      #00  pc 00000000000175e8  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+28)
      #01  pc 00000000000f64ad  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable4WaitEPNS_6ThreadE+80)
      #02  pc 00000000003e3275  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL12GoToRunnableEPNS_6ThreadE+500)
      #03  pc 00000000000e5bd5  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art12JniMethodEndEjPNS_6ThreadE+8)
      #04  pc 0000000000d9d2b5  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat (Java_android_os_BinderProxy_transactNative__ILandroid_os_Parcel_2Landroid_os_Parcel_2I+152)
      at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative (Native method)
      at android.os.BinderProxy.transact (Binder.java:503)
      at com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService$Stub$Proxy.a (IInAppBillingService.java:320)
      at com.android.billingclient.api.c$a.onServiceConnected (BillingClientImpl.java:839)
      at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected (LoadedApk.java:1223)
      at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run (LoadedApk.java:1240)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5438)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke! (Native method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:762)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:652)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/54871250/1381007

Answer (score 2):

There was an issue with the billing library, it is fixed in the release v1.2.1 in which they have moved **isBillingSupported** to the background thread.

Comment: yep. and they fixed another similar issue in version 1.2.2:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123117066